# On checkout page the text: "Do you Have a Coupon or Voucher?" Do you know where i can edit the text?

Tags: php, css, opencart

I am working on `Opencart` platform I want to remove some text from quick checkout page.

On checkout page the text:

> Do you Have a Coupon or Voucher?

Do you know where I can edit the text? Please suggest me

Comment: Search and Replace? If you can't find it it will be in the database possibly?

Comment: Where I can search...

Comment: @CoastalHomeandGift: In your source code maybe?

Comment: highlight message,

Comment: Do you mean Cart page? are you using default checkout?

Comment: Yes I am using default checkout...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using journal 2 Theme:

```
public_html/your website directory/catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/journal2/checkout/coupon_voucher_reward.tpl
```

or

```
public_html/catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/journal2/checkout/coupon_voucher_reward.tpl
```

Try if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

All text you see in your OpenCart shop are in corresponding language files. But in Journal theme this text placed here:

```
catalog\view\theme\journal2\template\journal2\checkout\coupon_voucher_reward.tpl
```

line:

```
<h2 class="secondary-title"><?php echo $this->journal2->settings->get('one_page_lang_coupon_voucher', 'Do you Have a Coupon or Voucher?'); ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using third party plugin for checkout because the default language line is

> Choose if you have a discount code or reward points you want to use or would like to estimate your delivery cost.

So there are three ways:

1. Search for the text inside language files of the source of plugin upload/catalog/language/ folder if you extract the plugin code.
2. Find the text in settings of that module by going to extensions section in admin panel.
3. It might be hard-coded inside the .twig or tpl file, so you can search inside the catalog/view/theme folder of the source of plugin.